# Accidentally deleted iPhoto and lost all of my photos, how can I get the photos back?

Tags: photos.app, photos

Not sure how I did it, but iPhoto is gone from my computer, along with all of my 800+ photos. How can I get my photos back? I reinstalled iPhoto and signed in, but it is empty.

Comment: Deleting the iPhoto.app should not have removed your pictures.  They should still be in the "/Users/$USER/Pictures/iPhoto Library" bundle.

Comment: If you are able to find your old iPhoto Library bundle using the finder, then restoring that is very easy. I suggest performing a search for "iPhoto Library". You should see two results. The larger will likely have all of your photos b

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you didn’t delete your iPhoto Library, but just iPhoto

1. Reinstall iPhoto from the Mac App Store [you did this, go to 2]
2. **Hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key while opening iPhoto** to select a different default library. The current default is the empty library. We want to track down your original library.
3. Click **“Choose library...”**
4. By default, your iPhoto Library is located in `/Volumes/<HDNAME>/Users/<USERNAME>/Pictures/`. Assuming you haven’t deleted the library itself, or moved it to a different location, your original iPhoto Library *will be* located in your pictures folder. It will be labeled `iPhoto Library_2.iphotolibrary`, `iPhoto Library.iphotolibrary~old` or something of that nature. I don’t know what the exact name will be. You will be able to tell the new from the old simply by examining the size (800 photos will be atleast a couple GB’s). **Select the old library.**
5. When iPhoto opens, your original library should be present and intact. If it’s not, you’ve just selected the current default library. Repeat steps 2-4 in this case.
6. Once you have identified the correct original library - using step 5 - you can now safely delete the empty (false) iPhoto Library from your pictures folder. Your original iPhoto library is now your default.